# How can I prevent counter from restarting?

Tags: c, timer, counter, stm32

I am currenlty working on a counter with a µs precision. Here's how I initialize it :

```
u32_ticks = (HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq() / 1000000);

pst_TimerHandle->Instance = RBC_TIM3_INSTANCE;
pst_TimerHandle->Init.Prescaler = u32_ticks - 1;
pst_TimerHandle->Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
pst_TimerHandle->Init.Period = 65535;
pst_TimerHandle->Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
pst_TimerHandle->Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(pst_TimerHandle) != HAL_OK)
{
    error_handling()
}
st_ClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(pst_TimerHandle, &st_ClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
    error_handling()
}
st_MasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
st_MasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(pst_TimerHandle, &st_MasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
    error_handling()
}
```

Would it be possible to prevent the counter from restarting to 0 once it reaches ARR value ? In other words, I would like my counter to stop right at 65535.

If yes, how would I make it restart from 0 on demand then ?

Thank you

EDIT : I am working on STM32F407 and I am planning on using a general purpose timer (TIM2 to 5 on this platform).

Comment: Is there a one-shot counter mode?

Comment: Can't you disable the timer when the timer event triggers?

Comment: There are a lot of different timers in the stm32 family. Please specify which mp/timer you are using.

Comment: @WeatherVane There is a single pulse mode and i try to use it but i don't know I felt like the solution was "dirty".

Comment: @stark That might just work ! I don't know why but I was thinking this morning that interrupt would be trigger on each counter increment but that's obviously not the case

Comment: @Damiano I updated the question accordingly

Comment: @stark So I tried to do what you were suggesting and unfortuantely it doesn't work. I read the documentation again and it actually can not work : "In upcounting mode, the counter counts from 0 to the auto-reload value (content of the 
TIMx_ARR register), then restarts from 0 and generates a counter overflow event". So yeah the counter is already reset to 0 when interrupt is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

OPM bit in TIMx_CR1 should do the work.

Within the HAL manual you should find reference to HAL_TIM_OnePulse_MspInit instead of HAL_TIM_Base_Init. If you have generated your app skeleton with CUBEMx there should be an option too.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. 
I don't know if I am doing it correctly, but it looks like CNT still go back to 0 and stop there. Is it a normal behavior ?

Comment: Think it's normal as the OPM register says that timer is disabled when an update event is generated. That update event is generated with the overflow of the counter.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. Thanks !